# yield - using element stored previously in list [Scala]

Tags: scala, recursion, element, yield

I will give a simplified code to explain my question easily:

- I have a user balance i.e. `val balance = 10`
- I have a list of data to iterate through using `for(elem <- dataList) yield (interest(elem, balance))`.

  - In my case interest is a method which will perform calculations on the given arguments and return a number which will be: **provided balance+the calculated interest**.

How can I use this newly returned value for the next element in my data list in yield so I could keep up-to-date my balance for the next elements in the list?

i.e. `for(elem <- dataList) yield (interest(elem, newBalanceFromPreviousYield))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there is no easy way to use it just with `yield`. Your use-case reminds fold pattern, so, let's use it. We accumulate balance and use it in `interest()` invocation:

```
dataList.foldLeft(List.empty[Int]) { (acc, elem) =>
  acc match {
    case Nil =>
      // if no balances accumulated yet, use default balance = 10
      List(interest(elem, balance))
    case all@newBalance :: _ =>
      // else use accumulated balance
      interest(elem, newBalance) :: all
  }
}.reverse // we need to reverse result list due to :: usage
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure from the question what do you want to get as result at the end: just final balance or list of balances for each element? Assuming that the latter one (since this is result type of for/yield applied to list), `scan` operation is what you need:

```
dataList.scanLeft(10)((acc, currentElem) => interest(currentElem, acc)).tail
```